# Does gravitation (or acceleration) make an observer see squeezed light and squeezed matter?

Tags: general-relativity, optics, gravity, quantum-optics, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I read at the end of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283911/) that Matta wrote:

> "If I put a quantum field on a spacetime and boost to an accelerating reference frame then the field modes undergo squeezing which is a Bogoliubov transformation (or, as I come from quantum optics, a symplectic transformation)."

I wonder if this sentence is correct.
Can we conclude that the Rindler observer sees squeezed light and squeezed electrons?
Can  we conclude that a motionless observer near a black hole is in a hot bath of squeezed matter?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "sees squeezed light..." Matta's statement is correct, but the Rindler observer can only access one of the two members of each squeezed pair, so the observer sees a *thermal* state. Think of a two-mode squeezed state with a partial trace taken over the inaccessible mode: the resulting reduced density matrix looks thermal. The black hole case is similar.